# How does "ancestral merit" work?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, repentance-teshuvah, zechut-merit

We see the usage of *Zechut Avot*, which I loosely translate as "ancestral merit" used in numerous circumstances to ask God to forgive our sins and wrongdoings. Moses used this several times such as forgiveness for the sin of the Golden Calf, when Israel complained about lack of meat and several other places.

We refer to this merit in various places in our prayers such as during *Tachanun* and *Selcihot*.

When does this work and when doesn't it? For example, Moses didn't refer to this after the sin of the spies. Ancestral merit didn't seem to ward off the Destruction of the Temples.

Does ancestral merit work only for certain types of sins? Is there some type of "expiration"? For example, is there a limit for how many sins or a frequency for which we can ask God to forgive us for such sins, but if we are "too sinful" this no longer works? Is ancestral merit meant to be a "supplement" for teshuva (repentance) or in what way is it meant to be used?

Comment: I think regarding expiration of zechut Avos please see link https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.55a?lang=bi . From מֵאֵימָתַי תַּמָּה זְכוּת אָבוֹת? אָמַר רַב: מִימוֹת הוֹשֵׁעַ בֶּן בְּאֵרִי, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אֲגַלֶּה אֶת נַבְלֻתָהּ לְעֵינֵי מְאַהֲבֶיהָ וְאִישׁ לֹא יַצִּילֶנָּה מִיָּדִי״.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, zechus avos seems to work in 2 ways.

1. **Behavioral**: By inheriting the zakus (purity of character) of the avos, we are more inclined to align ourselves with the ratzon Hashem in the long term, even if we have fallen short currently. One of the primary sources for this notion is in the Nephesh Hachayim, where Rb Chaim Volozhin discusses why in the following mishna

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%91

עשרה דורות מנח ועד אברהם

Avraham is just referred to by name, whereas in the following mishna

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%92

עשרה נסיונות נתנסה אברהם אבינו

Avraham is referred to as "avinu". He answers that by passing the 10 tests, Avraham bequeathed to us the purity of character to do the same, and in this regard he is "avinu".

2. **Hashem's plan for the world**: Hashem made a bris with the avos that they are their descendants would be central to Hashem's plan for the world. By invoking zechus avos we reconfirm our commitment to be part of that plan, and thereby request that Hashem should have mercy on us, despite our shortcomings, so we can continue to implement His plan for the world's destiny; in other words, to be mekadesh shem shamayim. This is a frequent theme in the tefillos of the yamim noraim, for example: Zachreinu le'chayim **le'maanchah** Elokim chayim.

Apparently we should say tamah zechus avos when neither of the above 2 mechanisms can be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Eliyahu Dessler in Michtav M'Eliyahu (cheilek alef - p.8) has an essay that focuses on understanding G-d's trait of Rachamim - mercy, and in particular, how it manifests itself along with Zechus Avos.

He focuses on the specific middos that the avos excelled in and notes how it is this that creates a link to future generations. Their devotion and mesirus nefesh to the cause is what creates is our innate, ancestral link. For this reason one should read it not as 'zechus' but rather 'zakus' meaning the purity of the avos.

He writes on p.15:

> הלא הבטיח השי"ת לאבות הקדושים כי תכלית כל הבריאה כולה תצא מהם וזרעם, וכל העתיד הגדול אשר יתגדל ויתקדש שמו של הקב"ה לעין כל, הלא יהיה על ידי משיח צדקינו. אבל הלא מאברהם אבינו ע"ה על דורו של משיח ישנן דורות הרבה, וכולם יוצאים אלו מאלו כמו השלשלת הארוכה, אשר טבעותיה דבוקות זו בזו. ובאופן כזה יש דורות או יחידים, שעל פי משפט מעשיהם אינם ראוים להתקיים, אבל מ"מ מתקיימים, לא בזכות עצמם אלא בזכות אבותיהם וצאצאיהם. כי הדור הזה, או האנשים הללו, המה כמו טבעת בשלשלת החבור ההיא, ובזה היא סבת קיומם, כי בלעדיהם אין חבור בין אבותיהם לדורות יבואו. אדם אשר כזה יתקיים בעולם הזה, אף שאין לו שום זכות לזה מצד עצמו
>
> *Did Hashem not promise to our holy forefathers that the purpose of all creation will come out of them and their seed, and all the great future which will grow and be sanctified in His name Hashem will be for all to see, and will it not be through Moshiach. But aren't there many generations from the point of Avraham avinu? All of them (i.e. the generations) come out of each other like a long chain whose rings are all linked with each other. And in this way there are generations or individuals, which according to the law of their deeds are not worthy of existence, but nevertheless they exist, not due to their own merits but the merits of their forefathers and their descendants. Because this generation, or these people, they are like rings in a chain that are interconnected, and this is the reason for their existence. Because without them, there would be no connection to the generations to come. A person like this will exist in this world, even though he has no right to it on his own part.*

So to answer your question it would seem from Rav Dessler that this ancestral merit serves to aid our continued existence even when we are deemed unworthy. They showed us the correct way to act and these traits are something that we as a nation have been gifted throughout the generations.

Answer (score -5):

The concept of zechut avot, “merits of the fathers" is problematic because it implies that the individual’s merit can be stored in a bank account and be used at a later date. The idea is linked to the flawed Christian notion called “original sin,” which some attribute to Genesis 1. Both ideas are contrary to the Torah. Thus, zechut avot "ancestor’s good deeds" is not a biblical concept at all. It follows that it does not [and cannot] work. How then, could Moses used his merit to save the Israelites?

Comment: Just because the Christians borrowed an idea does not make it invalid. And the idea that one is rewarded for his actions at a later date is ubiquitous. And that Adam eating from the Tree of Knowledge corrupted mankind is very clear in Genesis.

Comment: @N.T. Christianity did not borrow “original sin,” it invented it. I do not think Adam was cursed but punished. The notion of zechut avot is not found in the Torah at all.

Comment: See the discussion of Adam's sin in Derech Hashem. As for zechus avos, the pesukim in Devarim are very clear that Hashem's relation with us is due to His love for our forefathers.

Comment: @N.T. You're dealing here with someone who has no compunctions about making up statements and attributing them to Torah sources, and conversely denying clear statements in those sources. Don't waste your time.

Comment: @N.T. Again, “original sin” is a Christian notion that tragically crept into Judaism. Needless to say, we could interpret the many passages you mentioned differently. For example, we might say that Leviticus 26 is saying that G-d remembered the promise He made to the ancestors. Furthermore, Rambam in Guide, 3:53 defines zechut to say “giving everyone his own due.” But many people disagreed with Maimonides.

Comment: Similarly, in Exodus 32:11, 13, Moses is asking G-d to remember His promises to Abraham, Isaac, and Israel that their descendants will be as numerous as the stars.

Comment: @Meir This is outrageous. Where is there an untrue word in that statement? It’s all true! Just remember! You didn’t hear what you heard!

Comment: Nothing you said challenges the concept of zechus avos.

Comment: @TurkHill I know, right? It's also "all true" that Jews use Christian blood in matzos - after all, "we could interpret the many passages" that way. Go join your buddies at come-and-hear.com, and leave the rest of us alone.

Comment: "Nothing you said challenges the concept of zechus avos." That's your opinion, @N.T. Maybe, maybe not, but it still doesn't help the fact that the concept is not in the Bible.

Comment: @Meir Where have I said that "Jews use Christian blood in matzos?" I said no such thing. And I don't need your anti-semitic sites, I am a fan of [Rationalist Judaism](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/). PS So you now, every time you link us to that "Christian site" of yours, you're donating them $$.

Comment: @TurkHill Your "arguments," which involve making up things that don't exist and denying the ones that do, are exactly the same kind that have been used to "prove" that Jews use Christian blood for matzos. Your "rationalist Judaism" is neither rational nor Judaism. Just go away and leave us alone to talk about actual Judaism, not your ersatz version of it. (And in what way did I "link to" that site? It's not even a clickable link. Another lie of yours.)

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to agree with @Meir here.

Comment: @Meir Ok, not a link, but you shared the site, which only makes up lies about the Talmud. Here's a [real](http://talmud.faithweb.com/) Talmud site, which I prefer, thank you very much. Also, are you sure Rabbi Slifkin's [rational Judaism](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/) isn't Judaism? Have you ever clicked on the link to see for yourself, or do you prefer to run away?

Comment: @N.T. Just remember that this idea is alien to rational Judaism.

Comment: I am familiar with Slifkin's website, and his arguments are mostly against straw-man versions of z'chus avos, etc. The actual idea is everywhere; Deut. 10 for example.

Comment: @TurkHill "you shared the site, which only makes up lies about the Talmud." So, precisely what you're doing. And the notion that this is "donating them $$" is, of course, nonsense on stilts; speaking of "running away," how about admitting that you were wrong? And as for your "real Talmud site" - see, maybe your problem is that you're relying on such sites instead of learning the actual Talmud and other Jewish sources in the original, such that if anyone who seems to have credentials says that the Talmud (or Rambam, or the Zohar, etc.) says something, then it must be true. Some "rationalism."

Comment: @Meir Again, where have I shared a site which makes up lies about the Talmud? On the contrary, you shared such a site that, allegedly receives money whenever someone enters their site, or at least that is the rumor. And how about admitting that the site you shared was such a site, regardless of the circumstances?

Comment: @Meir Yes, my "real Talmud site" is by a respectable rabbi, R. Gil Student, member of the Rabbinical Alliance of America (RAA), the Igud HaRabbonim. But I do have a Talmud from my uncle. In addition, I own Everyman's Talmud by Abraham Cohen, amongst others. Yes, I agree that we should not always rely on scholars but read the actual primary sources.

Comment: @N.T.  I do not think Rabbi Slifkin's arguments were strawman but you can believe that if you want. In addition, I think G-d persevered the Jewish people because of His promise to Abraham, that his seed will become as numerous as the stars. I think that that is a good interpretation. Don't you?

Comment: How is that different than zchus avos?

Comment: @TurkHill No, you haven't shared such sites (and neither have I; referring to a site isn't "sharing" it). But you've made up your own ideas of what the Torah and the Talmud and the Zohar and the Rambam have said, just as those sites do. For example, you're mentioning R. Student's site, but of course he says no such thing as that zechus avos is an un-Jewish concept, because unlike you, he knows his sources and is honest about them. Look, I'm heartily tired of having to constantly knock down your strawmen and your lies and your so-called "rationalism." זיל גמור, then we'll talk.

Comment: @Meir Right! Because I never said that R. Student said that zechus avos were un-Jewish. Talk about strawman. As for Jewish "rationalism," you would check R. Slifkin's site, [Rationalist Judaism](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com). I think you will enjoy the site as much as me. Most of "those ideas" come from Jewish scourses, not Christian evangelical sites bashing the Talmud.

Comment: @TurkHill Then there was no reason to mention R. Student's site. You'd actually do well if you did learn from him, because then at least you'd have a slightly better picture of what is and isn't un-Jewish. As for R. Slifkin's site - I have seen it before; as N.T. has noted, there's a fair amount of strawman argument there too. At any rate, he also doesn't say what you're claiming. So at the end of the day, Turk, for all your fulminating about your so-called "rationalist Judaism," it turns out that you have no sources for any of your assertions. As I said, not rational, and not Judaism.

Comment: @Meir I mentioned R. Student's site to counter your claim about what Talmud sites I use. As for R. Slifkin, try actually reading rather than “skim.” And here are two more sites for free education: ["rationalist Judaism,"](http://libertarianjew.blogspot.com/2010/11/am-i-really-deist.html) and [zechut avot](https://booksnthoughts.com/the-strange-practice-of-rewarding-descendant-for-an-ancestors-good-deed/). Like it or not, rationalism *is* Jewish.

Comment: @TurkHill Don't put in quotation marks something ("skim") that I didn't say; that's another lie. How many are we up to now? As for R. Student - would that you had actually used his site in depth; at best maybe you've "skimmed" it. And as for your last two sites - let's see: the first describes him/her/itself as "formerly Orthodox," and the other is your Israel Drazin, whom you've previously quoted as saying, basically, that Rambam lied about his true beliefs ("holy lies," he calls them - see https://yediah.blogspot.com/2011/03/more-about-rabbi-dr-israel-drazins.html). Some "sources" those are.

Comment: And of course I notice that you've commented there too, with the same fact-free type of screeds as here.

Comment: @Meir Saying that I didn't read R. Student's site in depth *is* a lie. I have read almost every essay on that site. And as for the two other sites, Steve is an observant Jew, even if he isn't "Orthodox." Orthodox means following beliefs. The term Orthodox in Judaism was created by Reform Jews. Although I consider myself to be modern orthodox, I do not like titles such as Orthodox. I agree with everything the author wrote.

Comment: Abrahamson and Guttmann are not scholars of Rambam and are not a reliable authority on the thought of Rambam. Contrary, Rabbi Drazin is a true scholar. I like his work. Although not perfect (who is?), he is an honest and straight thinker. I like that. Anything that you read from him will be worth reading. He is right about a number of points he makes. Regarding zechut avot, he is right.

Comment: @TurkHill I think you might have gone around the bend. What statements of mine do you claim to be responding to?

Comment: @Meir wrote that he does not understand how "Rambam lied about his true beliefs ("holy lies," he calls them." Answering briefly now. Maimonides wrote for two audiences the intellectual and the commoner. One needs to read the entire Guide to know his true view. Maimonides did not call them "holy" lies and he did not lie, but wrote, “essential truths” – what Plato called “noble lies” – which has good intentions, because while untrue, they help people.